# How to Call Methods From Parent Classes Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

These are my results, I need myClass method1 to return again when c2.method1() is called. (Python 3) How would I go about this? The tutorial I am using says that calling c2.method1 should result in the last line "anotherClass method1" as well as "myClass method1" on a fourth line of results.

```
myClass method1
myClass method2: This is a string
anotherClass method1
```

This is the code.

```
class myClass():
def method1(self):
    print("myClass method1")

def method2(self, someString):
    print("myClass method2: " + someString)

class anotherClass(myClass):
def method2(self):
    print("anotherClass method2")

def method1(self):
    print("anotherClass method1")


def main():
c = myClass()
c.method1()
c.method2("This is a string")

c2 = anotherClass()
c2.method1()

main()
```

Comment: "The tutorial I am using" Which one? "says" Where?

Comment: The shown output is the normal behavior. If you need to call methods of super class, use `super()` (read the docs for details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call 'super()' in your subclasses initialization ( its  `__init__` ) you can call parent class methods :)

Comment: Not only in `__init__`, it can be used in any nearly any method.